# Bootstrap number input composed by two fields

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out if Bootsrap has a number input composed by two fields.

I want the number input to have two fields : one composed from strict 5 char and the second one to be composed from max 2 chars.

```
---------------------     --------
- 12345             -  -  - 12   -
---------------------     --------
```

Does anyone know if its posible with Bootstrap ?